# Phar from command line

Tags: php, phar

I have a Java application (.jar) and I use PHP as text report exporter language. Now I am trying to put all .php files inside .jar and use them like phar from PHP command line interpreter.

File `0.php` has content:

```
echo 0; require('phar://phar.zip/1.php');
```

File `phar.zip/1.php` has content:

```
echo 1; require('2.php');
```

File `phar.zip/2.php` has content:

```
echo 2;
```

Running from windows command line `php -n 0.php`, it works with output `012`.

Running from windows command line `php -n phar://phar.zip/1.php`, it doesn't work. It outputs

> Could not open input file: phar://phar.zip/1.php

**What could be the problem?**

It seems `php -r require('phar://phar.zip/1.php');` works as a workaround, but still I don't understand why command line cannot have `phar://`.

Comment: Windows uses backslashes as directory separator. Maybe it cannot separate the file `1.php` from the base `phar.zip`.

Comment: @cweiske separation of a command line parameter is not a windows thing. Php.exe does that job.